# Push segue briefly displays blank white screen before loading view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, storyboard, segue

In storyboard, I have a TableViewController and a push segue to a DetailViewController. The TableVC is nested in a nav controller. I set the DetailViewController view to background color black in storyboard. The DetailVC also contains a webview which loads in its viewDidLoad. I pass the webview's URL to DetailVC in TableVC's prepareForSegue.

I'm getting some strange behavior when the push segue is performed when tapping the cell. Immediately after the segue is performed, DetailVC's view bg color is white for a brief moment (nav bar shows up fine). Then the view's bg color turns to black (it was set to black in storyboard). Then the webview loads. I'm not sure what is causing the delay for DetailVC's view bg color.

Here is my prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Radio Show Playback"])
    {
        RadioShowPlaybackVC *radioShowPlaybackVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        radioShowPlaybackVC.radioShowData = self.radioShows[indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

**Edit:** It has something to do with the webview. When I remove the webview, the segue transitions as desired.

**Edit:** My current workaround is to hide the webview until it loads. When it hasn't loaded, the bg color displays white and cannot be modified.

Comment: You can also set the background colour of the web view (or possibly its scroll view?)

Answer (score 3):

In case you never fixed the problem, you should definitely listen to Vito's answer in regards to the main thread. But also add the following to your code:

```
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[webView setOpaque:NO];
```

If it's still showing white just change clearColor to blackColor.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you executed loadRequest, loadHTMLString:baseURL: or loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL: for the UIWebView in viewDidLoad

Both the segue transition and UIWebView will use the same main thread in order to accomplish their tasks thus "white"background was momentarily shown as the steps in changing the default "white" background to black background was momentarily paused due to activity in UIWebView.

Try to load the UIWebView in **viewDidAppear** thus the UIWebView will start consuming the main thread when the segue transition has been completed.

Comment: What you've said makes sense, but there still seems to be a "white" background delay.